# iphone app bundle / company identifier with ccTLD - what's the protocol?

Tags: iphone, bundle, app-id

whats the protocol when your domain name is

domainname.com.au

is it

au.com.domainname.app_id

or

com.au.domainname.app_id

or possibly

com.domainname.app_id

Bascially what do you do if you have a country code top level domain (ccTLD) and you want to start cranking out iPhone apps?

merci!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be `au.com.domainname.app_id`.

If you swapped the `au` and the `com`, then you could conflict with an app from the `au.com` domain.

If you omit the `au`, then you could conflict with an app from the `domainname.com` domain.

By always reversing your FQDN, you insure against conflicts like that.

Comment: perfect; that proof is irrefutable! I wish I had thought of it!